# Quickest way to grab lines from multiple Files

Tags: python, unix, parallel-processing, grep

I have files that vary in size, some are huge.  I have many of these files, all are compressed with lzop.

The files look like this :

```
nodedef>name VARCHAR,family VARCHAR,composite VARCHAR,color VARCHAR
1104283,C,1,'238,32,77' 0,1,4,'255,182,83' 1,1,4,'255,182,83'
7,1,4,'255,182,83' 11,1,4,'255,182,83' 12,1,4,'255,182,83'
13,1,4,'255,182,83' 14,1,4,'255,182,83'
```

I want to grab all lines that have a C in the second Col - a grep with ",C" will do this. How can I speed this up ?

The Lines that I am looking for will always be at the top of the file - however the number of lines may vary (should be no more than 20).  The file is ordered, so as soon as the line after a line  with a ",C" does not match the regex , there are no more ",C" in the file.

Should I look at parallelising the grep here (I have access to HPC with many cores)?

Thanks, 
R

EDIT:
There can be multiple matches within the same file (and the 'C' containing lines will always be clustered and at the top of the file)

Comment: If you're sure about the 20 lines, have you tried using head ?

Comment: There cannot be more than one line in the file with the 2nd column containing "C"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` may not be effective when it comes to search for a text in a particular column, but `awk` thrives in achieving just that.

If you are looking to process multiple files and there can't be more that one line that contains a line with `2nd` column value as `C` the following script would be sufficient.

```
# Am assuming the the `.txt` files are the ones you want to process

for i in *.txt; do
    [ -e "$i" ] || continue    # To handle when no input *.txt files present
    awk -F',' '$2 ~ /C/ { print }' "$i" >> MatchingLines.txt
done
```

Am creating a new file `MatchingLines.txt` whose contents will be appended with the line containing the `C` in each of the file you have. Even if the file contains multiple instances, all of them are appended into the output file.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear Inian, Thanks for the answer.  However, there can be multiple matches in a file.

Comment: @user1338194: It is not a problem, the updated answer takes care of that

Comment: @user1338194: Happy to help!

Comment: Not used awk in anger for a long time, but I think `awk -F',' '{if($2=="C"){matched=1;print;}else{if(matched)exit;}}' "$i"` will stop after outputing the first 'run' of matches. May need to test it more than I have to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the answer by @Inian for using awk for matching, a useful extention might be to use 'make' for easy (local) parallelism if you have many many files, or matching on some files can take a long-time:

```
inputs = $(wildcard *.txt)
outputs = $(inputs:.txt=.matches)

%.matches : %.txt
    ./findmatches.sh $< > $@

matches.all: $(outputs)
    cat $(outputs) > matches.all

all: matches.all
```

in a `Makefile`, and then use `make -j8` or similar so that make can process the files in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am a novice with Make. I am not sure I fully understand how to use the above.  This has inspired me to spend time learning about this.  Thanks.

Comment: I find reading them backwards makes it easier. In this case: `all` needs `matches.all` to be made... `matches.all` needs all of the *.matches files made... and the pattern-rule is what actually produces `foo.matches` from each `foo.txt`.

The parallelism trick is that make knows that it can apply the pattern-rule for making *.matches files can be done independently for each file and so can run several of them in parallel.